# Getting User Credentials Windows Authenication

Tags: asp.net

If a user has signed into their computer and are connected to an intranet, is there a way to grab the users crendtials and authentication them in asp.net? What specific code would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's very possible. See "Configuration Windows Authentication" section in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx

Essentially you allow IIS and ASP.NET to digest the windows user information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`